# What is getter/setter naming convention in java for a boolean such as canProduce?

Tags: boolean, naming-conventions

Will this get/set approach be correct?

```
boolean canProduce;
public boolean getCanProduce() {
    return canProduce;
}
public void setCanProduce(boolean canProduce) {
    this.canProduce = canProduce;
}
```

Or should I use an is/set approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the standard approach for booleans is the is/set approach as eclipse autogenerate code like that so I finally opted for an approach like this in order to have a more readable methods:

```
boolean ableToProduce;
public boolean isAbleToProduce() {
    return ableToProduce;
}
public void setAbleToProduce(boolean ableToProduce) {
    this.ableToProduce = ableToProduce;
}
```

Comment: Right, that is what I meant. I will change it. Thanks